# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn not populating values from the data source

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview in a tabpage. the datagridview has 6 columns. The 6th column is a comboboxcolumn. I am trying to bind a datasource to the comboboxcells. Each row would have different datasource based on the row number. The datagridview will have 10 rows always. The problem is the comboboxes are not populating any values. It just gives me blank item. Both datagrid and comboboxcolumn datasources showing data table values when if I keep break points.Could someone tell me what I am missing here?

```
 private void BuildFreshAccessMatrix()
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
       DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboPermissionCol = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[5];
        //cboPermissionCol.DataPropertyName = "UserLevelCategoryName";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataProvider.GetBlankMatrixData();
        int i = 1;


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboPermission = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(row.Cells["UserLevelCategoryNameAdd"]);
            cboPermission.DataSource = dataProvider.GetPermissionComboData(i);
            cboPermission.DisplayMember = "UserLevelCategoryName";
            cboPermission.ValueMember = "UserLevelCategoryName";
            i += 1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Debugging `dataProvider.GetPermissionComboData(i)` gives you the right  amount of items and of the right type?

Comment: Yes. It gives me the right data table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to :

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboPermission = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["UserLevelCategoryNameAdd"];
```

instead of :

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboPermission = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
(row.Cells["UserLevelCategoryNameAdd"]);
```